# Report: How often users edit records

Tags: reporting

I would be interested in creating a report on how often my users edit records. I have played around with this for a while, but have got nowhere. I can only really use the last modified date, but I don't think there is really a report on how often a user edits something, is that right?
Tia, Lily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to track changes to specific fields, you could enable history tracking for those fields, and then run a history report and do a summary on the user. There is a limit of 20 fields though.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&language=en

If you want to track more than 20 fields then you would have to go for a trigger that will log each change into another object. Then either use a summary report or some custom console on that object to summarize and present the data.